# Two of my answers from June both got accepted within one minute -- coincidence?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I am not sure if this is a spooky coincidence or a bug, but I am intrigued as to what caused this! I have been away for a week and came back today to +30 rep, coming from two answers which were both accepted.

- [Answer 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1820511/244596) was posted on June 10 at 2:58, and accepted on December 13 at 23:33.
- [Answer 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1820467/244596) was posted on June 10 at 2:01, and accepted on December 13 at 23:34.

Checking reputation feed in my profile, it does not look like the rep was duplicated, but I wonder if it was delayed somehow. Then again, checking the profiles of the question-askers, they were both 'last seen' at 23:33 and 23:34 respectively...

Surely this cannot be a coincidence?

Comment: There is a natural explanation to this, but finding it requires tools only diamond moderators have access to. Some of you can undoubtedly figure it out from what I said already (rolls eyes). Anyway, there is nothing that you should worry about. Enjoy the well earned addition to your rep score!

Comment: Both users who asked those questions have exactly four answers, one question, have been members for about ten months, have around 200 reputation, have around the same number of profile views, and have generic pictures... the mystery deepens?

Comment: Just kidding, as Jyrki said, it's probably a coincidence. Well done!

Comment: @SkeletonBow actually that's not what Jyrki said except I misunderstood completely.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Well OP, in any case, don't worry.

Comment: @SkeletonBow Aha, I will take the rep and not complain! It does make me curious what the natural explanation the diamonds are seeing, though. There is a conspiracy somewhere here :-)

Comment: If the two questions were asked from the same account, you likely would not be surprised at the fact somebody might accept answers for two of their questions close in time.